# MPI Bcast to change globals in C

Tags: c, mpi

I'm having difficulties with the following functionality. I'm allowing each process to perform work on the global array. Each process starts with the same global array, but if it changes, it has to update the other processes' array.

```
//Globals
float * globalArray;

int main() {
    //Sequential code to init globalArray
    int size = //Length of globalArray
    int rank;
    int x, i;
    MPI_Init();
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    while(x == 0) {
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            printf("Values of array: %f\n", globalArray[i]);
        }
        workOnArray();
        x = getCondition();
        MPI_Bcast(&globalArray, size, MPI_FLOAT, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Finalize();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the global arrays in the other processes aren't updated when I Bcast it.

Comment: That code's crazee !  What's `MPI_Finalize` doing inside the `while` loop ?

Comment: A broadcast sends data from *one* process to all processes. It does *not* magically synchronize changes from different processes. You need to properly decompose your data among ranks and then use other collectives depending on what data each rank needs, and what data it updates.